# Dynamically change the font size in Birt

Tags: birt

I am using a Dynamic Text in Birt. I want to display a sentence on one line but if it's too width it's displayed on two or more. Is there a way to dynamically decrease the font size when the sentence is too width so it stays on one line?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

first choose your cell and then click on  the script tab,there choose onRender from the drop-down and put this code
**this.getStyle().fontSize**   this gives you to change the fontsize dynamically while rendering the page...
Cheers..

Comment: `this.getStyle().fontSize` let me set the font size. But how to detect if my sentence is displayed on more than one line?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution - building on what @Sundar said.

In my case I have two fields in one cell. It is not perfect, but the only way I have to know when the text is "too big" is to measure the length of the combined strings and then adjust the font size accordingly.

Click on the cell and then the script tab, and enter code like this in the onRender script

```
// Decide if we need to change font size.
totalLength = 0;
if (row["Field Name 1"]) {
   totalLength += row["Field Name 1"].length;
}
if (row["Field Name 2"]) {
   totalLength += row["Field Name 2"].length;
}

// Make the font smaller with larger amounts of text.
switch (true) {
    case (totalLength > 200):
      this.getStyle().fontSize = "6pt";
        break;
    case (totalLength > 100 && totalLength < 200):
      this.getStyle().fontSize = "8pt";
        break;
    default:
      this.getStyle().fontSize = "10pt";
        break;
}
```